Is it possible to solve for a function of a differential in an integral equation?
I am attempting to solve an equation for $\nu(x)$. The exact equation is part of my PhD research and is needlessly complex for the core of my issue, I will give a simplified example instead:
$\int_{R\backslash\{0\}} f(x,y) \nu(dy) = g(x)$.
Assume $f$ and $g$ are sufficiently well-behaved for this integral to work (feel free to choose specific $f$ and $g$ in your answer if you need more details to demonstrate a point) and $R$ represents the set real numbers. My idea is to somehow apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to both sides after differentiating to obtain a differential equation, but for whatever reason I am stuck on dealing with how $\nu$ would interact with the FTC part 1. This would be easy if we had something like $\nu(dx)=h(x)dx$ instead (for some function $h$), but I do not see how I could rewrite this equation like that without knowing $\nu$ already.
For those wondering about context. I am trying to manually solve for the Levy measure of a particular stochastic process by equating the exponent of the Levy-Khintchine formula (left) to the exponent of the characteristic function (right). I have never been taught to manually solve for the Levy measure, we always just used intuition and comparison in class. So if there is any literature or formulas known to find a Levy measure directly, I will be grateful.

The integral on the LHS is a number while the RHS is a function in $x$. Is there a typo somewhere?

Thank you for the correction. In my setting, there's several variables and so I oversimplified in the above example. It is fixed now!

I’m still confused as to how you’re aiming to apply FTC. The domain of integration is fixed, not varying depending on $x$. In what sense does FTC applies?

@KevinDietrich The earlier version of this question referred to $\nu$ as a measure. Given the final paragraph about the context for the question, that’s likely still what it refers to, in which case what you wrote is not how measures work. But this edited version of the question is making it quite confusing.

Also, maybe there’s more context here, but is there a reason why you can’t just assume $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure so $\nu(dy) = h(y)dy$? In that case $\int f(x, y) , \nu(dy) = \int f(x, y) h(y) , dy$ is an integral transform of $h$. The integral transform in question may admit an inverse (depending on what $f$ is, of course), in which case you may be able to obtain $h$ by applying the inverse of this integral transform to $g$. (More generally, maybe $\nu$ corresponds to a distribution and the integral transform in question applies to distributions as well?)
